# Print part of webpage - css not shown

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

I try to print part of my website but when I try to do this, the css properties are not shown. The thing is that I have my css information embedded in my html file. Do you have a solution for that?

```
var content = document.getElementById("div id");
var WinPrint = window.open('', '');
WinPrint.document.write(content.innerHTML);
WinPrint.document.close();
WinPrint.focus();
WinPrint.print();
WinPrint.close();
```

Thanks!

Comment: I assume you did not embed your CSS in the element which you are copying to the other window, did you?

Comment: I think you should include your CSS with an external file (separating markup from style information). Afterwards Sankar Raj's answer should work as it include a CSS file for rinting (media = print).

Comment: Are there any workarounds, because I need to have my css embedded?

Comment: You could copy the style tag the same way as you did with your content container. Remember to set the media to print.

Comment: well, this doesn't work neither :/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Just embed your CSS file like this...

```
    var content = document.getElementById("div id");
    var WinPrint = window.open('', '');
    WinPrint.document.write( "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"style.css\" type=\"text/css\" media=\"print\"/>" );
    WinPrint.document.write(content.innerHTML);
    WinPrint.document.close();
    WinPrint.focus();
    WinPrint.print();
    WinPrint.close();
```